# Windows Python path - unable to read file

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, filenames

I am trying to read an image: test_image.png (as shown in the screenshot below).

I have tried various combinations - but unable to get it right.

(in the screenshot - docs - jupyter source file is where my python code below is writen)

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

filename = r"C:\Users\First.lastname\OneDrive - CompanyName Inc\Workspace\PythonWorkspace\test_image.png"
img1 = np.array(Image.open(filename))
```

Error:  FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory:

[Screenshot of my file and location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY4JX.png)

How can I read files? I am on Windows 10, using Anaconda Python 3.

I have searched to resolve this issue but it doesn't seem to work. I have also tried without the "r", using "/" instead of "", and also "\" etc. (after reading answers to similar questions on stackoverflow)

My path has "." and " " (space) in it - is this causing issues?

I have also tried to remove the entire path and only use "test_image.png" in the same folder as my .ipynb - still get the same error.

Comment: Maybe Im tripping, but in your screenshot its looks like theres a extra whitespace in the file name after the word 'test'.
Its 'test _image.png' instead of 'test_image.png'.

Comment: Oh sorry, it doesn't have a space (I've edited the image to look more generic)